# Leaflet zoom control position error

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I want to change the position of the zoom control to `'topRight'`. Following is my code (here coords, zoom, subDomains and attrib are previously defined):

```
var map = L.map('map', {zoomControl: false}).setView([coords.latitude, coords.longitude], zoom);

L.control.zoom({
    position: 'topRight'
}).addTo(map);

L.tileLayer(mapquestUrl, {
    subdomains: subDomains,
    attribution: attrib,
    maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);
```

This is giving me `TypeError: n is undefined` in firefox and `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined` in chrome.

Removing `{zoomControl: false}` and `L.control.zoom({ position: 'topRight'}).addTo(map);` is working fine with default control position at top left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a typing error, you must write 'topright', not 'topRight'

[Control Positions reference](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-positions)

Comment: Dayum!!! I was like 100% sure I saw 'topRight' somewhere. Thanks for pointing this out. What a trivial blunder.